# Using VLCJ for DVB-T tuner

Tags: java, swing, vlcj, dvb

In our country there is a dvb frequency of 570000000 with 3 channels/programs; 16,17,18

This is the mrl i am using to change channel for vlc via batch file by replacing the **:program** value.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" dvb-t://frequency=570000000:bandwidth=8 :dvb-adapter=0 :live-caching=1000 :program=16
```

But when i use the same mrl via VLCJ it seems the **:program** does not have any effect and randomly show channel without changing code.

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;


public class VLCJTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();

        final MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = factory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();

        String str = "dvb-t://frequency=570000000 :bandwidth=8 :dvb-adapter=0 :live-caching=1000 :program=16";

        mediaPlayer.playMedia(str);

        Thread.currentThread().join();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve how to change of channel/program of digital tv via VLCJ mrl?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string must be split into MRL and separate "options":

```
String mrl = "dvb-t://frequency=570000000";
String[] options = {
    ":bandwidth=8",
    ":dvb-adapter=0",
    ":live-caching=1000",
    ":program=16"
};
mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
```